# Is there a way to include HTML inside of PhP Tags?

Tags: php, html, escaping

I am working on a Content management system, which can be found here: https://ostcms.tinii.biz/ but I am having a serious issue.

The concept behind it is making the user experience easy, but still providing a hands on experience with PhP, and I want to be able to have a variable called '$content' that the user can put plain HTML text into.

Example:`$content="<img src="/taco.png>";`

This does not work, however putting in text formatting tags does.

I was considering allowing the user to just put an image after each paragraph with a $image1, $image2, etc. variable, but I would prefer to simply have the user put all of the text into one

Comment: Does your vague "This does not work" refer to the string syntax error?

Comment: You're missing a double quote btw, but should be done like `$content="<img src='/taco.png'>";` or like Dan's method.

Comment: Well yes, I mean that's the point of PHP...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I know, I was just putting it as an exampl.

Comment: PHP has absolutely no knowledge of HTML. it's just text, which means you can put any html you want into a string, as long as you obey PHP's string syntax rules: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: You can use PHP's Heredoc. That way you can use both single and double quotes if you need do: `<<<HERE  ...HTML here...  HERE;` . Look here http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.string.php. Note that the `HERE` needs special indentation the `HERE;` and `<<<HERE` needs to be on their own line without whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in the string, or use single quotes within the HTML"

```
$content="<img src=\"/taco.png\">";

$content="<img src='/taco.png'>";
```